# VueJS: Need to be able to clone a div and bind to a cloned (different) v-model as well

Tags: vue.js

I have a `div` containing some code that I'd like to duplicate each time I push a button. The catch is it needs to 2-way bind to another v-model and display another set of variables which the user types in. Then it needs to happen again a third time and a fourth ... up to however many times the button is clicked.

I made a fiddle: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zg1fcwLk/3/)

Right now I can duplicate with the plus sign button but all clones are bound to the same v-model. I hope this all makes sense.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make clones of template elements in a `v-for` loop by cloning their state. For example, create a default object, and every time you want to create a clone, push a copy of that object in the list of elements.

```
<div class="flexMeTop" v-for="accordian in accordianList" :key="accordian.id">
    <input
        v-model="accordian.policyMapName"
        placeholder="99/KRFS/010573//SYG"
        maxlength="20"
        class="widthAuto"
        />
    // and so on...
</div>

data() {
    return {
        accordianList: [],
        newObject: {
            policyMapName: null,
            siNumber: null,
            serviceInstance: null,
            rateLimit: null,
            selectedService: null
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    addAccoridanList: function() {
        this.accordianList.push(Object.assign({}, this.newObject));
    }
}
```

See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6tu0aqr/2/

Comment: This is fantastic! How will I render each one down below and make them show up differently in brackets `{{ policyMapName1 }}` `{{ policyMapName2 }}` for example

Comment: you could use their index: `{{ accordianList[0].policyMapName }}`